# PHP json_encode values are only literal value of 'object'

Tags: php, jquery, json

SOLVED - EDIT: I ended up not having to do json parse nor stringify with return from php because I can already do data[i]["filesize"]

code below is only showing me http://pastebin.com/DZ4UyHjC

if I change code to dataType:text then it outputs http://pastebin.com/pZg2W2aL which validates on site jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com . So with datatype:text, i would try to manually parse it with JSON.parse(result), this brings me back to original issue/output in first paste.
I've tried the suggestion of setting utf8 encoding, setting header in php before echo but still the same issue. Any help?

```
    if(mysqli_num_rows($fres)){
        $row =  array();
        while ($frow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fres)) {
            $row[] = array("path"=>myhtmlspecialchars($frow['path']),"filesize"=>mksize($frow['filesize']));            }
    echo json_encode($row);
```

///end of php

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './getFilesList.php',
        data: {id : varId},
            dataType: 'JSON',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` ?  Without the existance of a param to tell jquery what the response is, it will try to guess and can auto parse json into objects for you.

Comment: woah, it is fixed with JSON.stringify . thank you. also title typo, meant to say literal value of 'object'